# r subset dataframe for only certain columns

Tags: r

I'd like to take a subset of a dataframe and keep observations where only certain columns are NA and not others. For example:

```
d <- data.frame(cat=c(1, 2, NA, NA), dog=c(3, 3, NA, 1), rabbit=c(.1, .2, .3, .4), python=c(3, 3, 3, 3))
d
    cat dog rabbit  python
1   1.0 3.0 0.1 3.0
2   2.0 3.0 0.2 3.0
3   NA  NA  0.3 3.0
4   NA  1.0 0.4 3.0
```

How do I elegantly get only observation 4, i.e. the only observation for which `cat`, and only `cat` is NA? I know that I can do

```
d2 <- subset(d, is.na(cat)&!is.na(dog)&!is.na(rabbit)&!is.na(python))
    cat dog rabbit  python
4   NA  1.0 0.4 3.0
```

but this is cumbersome when I have lots of features, e.g. I have 20 features and I want a subset of data where only 4 of them are NAs. Is there a more elegant way to do this than to type out `is.na(featureOmitted)` and `!is.na(featureKept)` for every single `featureOmitted` and `featureKept` that I want? And once I have a dataframe of those particular observations, how do I drop the NA columns by which I applied the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
d[is.na(d$cat)&!rowSums(is.na(d[setdiff(names(d), "cat")])), , drop= FALSE]
# cat dog rabbit python
#4  NA   1    0.4      3
```

---

Or instead of `rowSums`, we can use `Reduce` with `|`

```
d[is.na(d$cat) & !Reduce(`|`, lapply(d[setdiff(names(d), "cat")], is.na)),, drop= FALSE]
```

---

A compact option would be

```
d[rowSums(is.na(d))==1 & is.na(d$cat),]
```